# 500 Error When Accessing robots.txt File in Django App Hosted on HestiaCP: Need Help Fixing the Issue

Tags: python, django, robots.txt, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I just tried to publish web-site using the Django App, the organization gave me the HestiaCP for host it. Everything works grate, but I have one and only problem. When I tryed to get the robots.txt file it gives me the 500 error. It still work correctly when I run it on the localhost.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwrPC.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjHiu.png)

Hestia gave me that log:

```
353868 could not find named location "@fallback", client: ***.***.***.***, server: *************.***, request: "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1", host: "*****************.***"
```

I hide the ip and site name by the *. Sorry for that. But still.

I thought that its not a problem when Bing index that page, but when I goes into Google search console... It even cant parse the sitemap.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpFjQ.png)

Have someone know what I should to do?

I have no idea how to fix it. But here you can give me some useful tips for fix it. I hope someone know how fix it.

Comment: What is your code for `@fallback`.  I think the log message says there is a problem in your code.